# quill : drop content at the position under the pointer

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor, quill

In some editors, when you want to drag and drop a piece of text from outside it, the cursor follows the mouse pointer and you can drop at the position of the mouse pointer, the cursor being below it.
In my case, I have a problem because the text is dropped where I set the cursor position before dragging the text (taken from outside the editor), whatever the actual position of the mouse pointer at the moment of dropping. The text cursor in the editor is not following the mouse pointer.

Do you think I made a mistake somewhere in my code, i.e. is there a simple way to achieve that behaviour ?

Thanks (again) !

Comment: Can you clarify the question? I'm not sure I understand the scenario.

Comment: edited the question for clarity (I hope !) :-)

Comment: I'm able to do this on quilljs.com on Chrome. Please file a github issue if it's browser specific. Otherwise can you reduce your code to a minimal size that still has this issue and post it?

Comment: I see now that I can do it as well with Firefox on quilljs.com. I'll try to digg a bit more into my code and come back if I'm completely stuck. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: After about six years any solution ? :)

Comment: @Batuhan: Reply by a user named Damir in an answer (I assume it is the same person as OP): "Sorry, no, the project is dormant (not completely dead) and I didn't have time to work on it again."